# Why Runnable.run() method was made to return no output

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to understand why `Runnable.run` method was made to take nothing as input and return nothing as output?

I understand that a thread's local variable (reference or primitive) has to come from own stack, but system could have been made to initialized. Put another way, I don't think it is technically impossible (but I may be wrong).

Comment: What do you mean by "could have been made to initialized"? It's not at all clear what you're actually proposing.

Comment: Out of curiosity: In your opinion, what parameters/return value should it have?

Answer (score 7):

Returning something is useful and is supported by Callable which can return one object.

```
Future<MyReturnType> ret = executor.submit(new Callable<MyReturnType>() {
    public MyReturnType call() throws Exception {
         // do something
         return new MyReturnType(value1, value2 ...);
    }
});
```

As you can see Callable can return a value because the ExecutorService supports holding passing the value back to the thread with the Future object.  This was only added in Java 5.0, so before this having `Runnable` returning a value wouldn't have been useful as there was no where for this return value to go.

---

Runnable doesn't need to take any arguments as it is an object which can hold any number of fields. e.g.

```
 static void bgLog(final Level level, final String message, final Throwable t) {
    logExec.submit(new Runnable() {
        // the anonymous nested class implicitly holds a copy of the final arguments above.
        public void run() {
           LOG.log(level, message, t);
        }
    });
 }
```

As you can see, the run() method can use any number of values which as passed implcitly by virtue of the fact the Runnable is an object, not just a holder for a method.

Answer (score 6):

A `Runnable` is meant to be like that, what you are probably looking for is a `Callable` instead, which does return a value via its `call()` method. And it is not true that you cannot pass arguments to a `Runnable`: it just depends on your implementation of the interface. Same goes for `Callable`.

Java has plenty of facilities to make `Callable`s run asynchronously as well: see `ExecutorService`. And read [this](http://www.jcip.net) for a full picture.

Answer (score 4):

The contract of `Runnable` makes it a perfect raw material out of which higher-level abstractions are constructed. It is a good example of the *Separation of Concerns* principle.

`Runnable`'s primary design goal was to represent an entry point to a new thread of execution. It does not represent a function or even a computation: just code that runs on another thread. Taking that into account, the `void run()` method signature makes perfect sense. If it accepted arguments, that would only burden the many use cases where you **don't** want to pass in arguments.

The case for the void return value is even clearer: once a thread is started, it has noone to report to, so the very concept of a return value would be just a tack-on.

Answer (score 3):

What would you rather have?

As it is, the class the implements [`Runnable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) can be initialized with a constructor which gives you absolute freedom to do anything wrt. initialization. As for not returning anything, there's always the [`Callable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) interface, that allows for a return value.

Perhaps you should consider these the interface equivalents of void and non-void methods :-)

Cheers,